# show hide alternate div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to implement a js/jquery program in which the steps are as follow 
when someone click button 1 then wrapper div first is hide and wrapper div of 2 button (second ) is shown . similarly for third and forth

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">
        <div class="content">content1</div>
        <button class="button">1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="content">content2</div>
        <button class="button">2</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">
        <div class="content">content1</div>
        <button class="button">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="content">content2</div>
        <button class="button">4</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this but know it will not work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    console.log($( this));
    $( this ).closest(".wrapper .second").hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please rewrite the question or the code so they match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check what the parent class is. If its `first` hide element and show the next, else hide element and show prev, like so:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    if($(this).parent().attr('class')=='first'){
      $(this).parent().hide();
      $(this).parent().next().show();
    }else{
      $(this).parent().hide();
      $(this).parent().prev().show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="first">
           <div class="content">content1</div>
           <button class="button">1</button>
       </div>
       <div class="second">
           <div class="content">content2</div>
           <button class="button">2</button>
       </div>

</div>

<div class="wrapper">
       <div class="first">
          <div class="content">content1</div>
          <button class="button">3</button>
      </div>
      <div class="second">
        <div class="content">content2</div>
        <button class="button">4</button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you could just toggle a class:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('div').add($(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.hidden')).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    <div class="content">content1</div>
    <button class="button">1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="second hidden">
    <div class="content">content2</div>
    <button class="button">2</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    <div class="content">content1</div>
    <button class="button">3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="second hidden">
    <div class="content">content2</div>
    <button class="button">4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('div').add($(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.hidden')).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your HTML the same, replace your javascript with:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    $( this ).closest(".wrapper").find(":hidden").show();
    $( this ).closest("div").hide();
});
$('.second').hide();
```

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fo19qoaa/1/)